# throwing an error on an api call that doesn't

Tags: javascript

We're using a 3rd party api with a success / fail callback, used as so:

```
    ThirdPartyAPI.checkIfLoggedIn(function (response) {
       if (response.status === 'connected') {  
           console.log("success");
       } else {
           console.log("failed");
         }
       }
    });
```

Their API doesn't have an error handler, and we've run into a situation whereby we don't get anything back from the API call-- it vanishes into the ether.  I was wondering how other people handle this situation-- do you wrap these calls in a `setTimeout`, and throw an error yourself?  Other options?

Comment: I noticed you already accepted my answer, but I just made a couple edits to it, so you might want to take another look at it.

Comment: I'll do so, many thanks for the answer (and edits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify `checkIfLoggedIn` yourself that is your only solution. It would look something like this (with a timeout of 5 seconds):

```
function checkIfLoggedIn ( ) {

    var max_wait = 5000,
        timed_out = false;

    var timer = setTimeout( function ( ) {
        timed_out = true;

        // Handle the timeout here
        console.log( "timeout" );

    }, max_wait );

    ThirdPartyAPI.checkIfLoggedIn(function (response) {

       if ( timed_out === true ) {
           // Ignore the response if we already handled a timeout
           return;
       }

       clearTimeout( timer );

       if (response.status === 'connected') {  
           console.log("success");
       } else {
           console.log("failed");
       }

    });
}
```